# Socket.io : Do I need to disconnect the client after every new message in a socket.io chat app?

Tags: socket.io

I am new to web-sockets. I was reading [this article](https://medium.com/@parthkamaria/building-a-chat-app-with-mean-stack-and-socket-io-c73b012b9fc9) on medium and [in a part of the client code](https://gist.github.com/parthkamaria7638/f1a86ee63e07c4d2d3f4cb2469e7a27d#file-websocket-service-ts-L27), the code disconnects the socket every time a new message is emitted.

Why is it so? Does this have some design advantage, is this how it is done?

Why not leave the socket connected for more message streams?

-----**EDIT**------

Here is the code that I am talking about. The code is from [this blog](https://medium.com/@parthkamaria/building-a-chat-app-with-mean-stack-and-socket-io-c73b012b9fc9)

```
  newMessageReceived() {
    const observable = new Observable<{ user: String, message: String}>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('new message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        // Why is the coder disconnecting the socket here?
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    });
    return observable;
  }
```

Comment: @ggorlen, thanks for the edit. Could you please help with the answer?

Comment: no you should not be discounected from the socket connection after emiting. there's someting wrong with your code, please give more info.

Comment: @Faramarz It is not my code it is open source code that I was looking at in a bid to learn how to use sockets.io. The link to the code is in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Faramarz I have just added the more info you requested.